# How to interpret the '3' notation underneath the first two quavers?

Tags: notation, rhythm, meter, tuplet

[image]

I'm trying to adapt a guitar piece to the piano. The piece, shown [here](https://www.jellynote.com/en/guitar-sheet-music-tabs/kai-rosenkranz/gothic-3-geldern-night#tabs:B), is in 3/4.

I've never seen this bit of notation before and I initially thought it was the indicator telling you to play 3 notes in 2 similar notes' worth of time, but it covers two quavers, so it can't be that. The notes without the rest seem to add up to 3 as well.

Comment: Where is this excerpt from? The fact that one of the notes is in a different direction from the others may be a sign that the sheet music is poorly written.

Comment: The excerpt comes from https://www.jellynote.com/en/guitar-sheet-music-tabs/kai-rosenkranz/gothic-3-geldern-night#tabs:B

Comment: Ah, I think I completely missed the 3 above the 3rd quaver while looking at it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's definitely a mess; there are a couple of notational aspects that suggest the person that did this is not well-versed in notational norms.

Listening to the recording on the [website](https://www.jellynote.com/en/guitar-sheet-music-tabs/kai-rosenkranz/gothic-3-geldern-night#tabs:B) you listed in the comments, it's clear that the triplet figure should encompass the first *three* eighth notes, not just the first two. (Indeed, there is a weird 3 above the stem-up pitch.) Here's a better way of notating this:

[image]

But I think it's actually more difficult than that. The piece is pretty clearly in 6/8, but the person notated it in 3/4 (!). The more "correct" notation would be something like this:

[image]

This latter notation looks odd, but that's because it's an odd rhythm. I recommend you slow it down enough so that you can focus on each eighth note (i.e., think of it as six notes in a measure, not a large duple measure). Once you're comfortable
with that, then speed it up to get the real 6/8 duple feel.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight regarding the signature, it does make more sense for it to be in 6/8. This changed my view on the whole song. For the record, the original on which the sheet on the website is based can be listened to here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCtV4DYZkK0 I do not think the composer ever released the official tabs.

Comment: @B.M. Thanks for the link; it's definitely in 6/8! And even the above rhythm is a little inexact; it's played pretty freely, so I think it's best you just try and mimic the original recording rather than playing it in a precisely metrical way.

Comment: Why would the first 3 notes need the triplet sign over them? In 6/8, that's how they get played regardless.

Comment: @Tim Because the beamed portion is actually played within the first *two* eighth notes of the measure. (It's an odd rhythm!) I'm still a little unhappy with how I have that notated; please let me know if you have any other suggestions!

Comment: @Tim that was my first take, but as Richard points out, he's squeezing the rest and two eighth-notes into the first two eighths of the first triplet.

Answer (score 5):

We could try to guess what that notation meant, but it would only BE a guess.  If the two bars are supposed to be the same length, the two dotted 8s add up to...    No, I'm not even going to try.  It's a mess.  Just possibly if you showed us the whole page, or at least a whole line of music it might make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the entire sheet for the lead guitar can be seen here, I'd share a screenshot but I think that'd be against the site's rules: https://www.jellynote.com/en/guitar-sheet-music-tabs/kai-rosenkranz/gothic-3-geldern-night#tabs:B

Comment: Upon reading that sheet music, I agree with this answer--there's no way we can interpret what's really going on without listening to the song. There are several notation errors in it--bars with only 2 beats (or more than 3 beats) and no time signature change, grace notes with note lengths *longer* than the notes they're for...that the tabs look self-published don't help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is indeed a site where people can self-publish sheet music. I'll try to write down the closest thing to what I hear, good to know I cannot rely on the quality of this particular sheet.